# Firefox won't load script tag of type "module"

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, ecmascript-6

I am trying to run ES6 JavaScript in Firefox using a local server. Because of this, I need to use a script tag of type `"module"` rather than `"text/javascript"`. The following works in Chrome but not Firefox. Help?

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Comment: You're relying on brand new experimental functionality. Have you explored more standard approaches like bundling?

Answer (score 2):

We just ran into this issue today, as we still use Firefox ESR 52 and haven't migrated to ESR 60 yet.

In Firefox 60 this feature is enabled by default. [Check out the Firefox 60 release notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/60#JavaScript).

In versions 54 to 59 you can enable it via *about:config* and setting *dom.moduleScripts.enabled*. [Noted in the script element docs (implementation notes drop down)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility).

Browsers that support ES6 modules will ignore scripts with a nomodule. So you could have a script with nomodule as a fallback. Like so:

```html
    <!-- in case ES6 modules are supported -->
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- in case ES6 modules aren't supported -->
    <script src="main-fallback.js" defer nomodule></script>
```

**Resources**

The suggestion above is quoted from [here](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2017/04/04/es6-modules-support-lands-in-browsers-is-it-time-to-rethink-bundling/#the-new-setup-using-native-supported-es6-modules) and [here](https://blog.cloud66.com/an-overview-of-es6-modules-in-javascript/#usinges6modules).

Here's another resource from [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/).

Answer (score 0):

See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

For type.module, on FF: User must explicitly enable this feature.

> This feature is behind the dom.moduleScripts.enabled preference (needs to be set to true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit about:config.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved the same issue.

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

should be changed to

```
<script type=module src="main.js"></script>
```

type attribute **module** shouldn't be wrapped by " "

In this case, es6 modules work in Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox.

Comment: This isn’t correct https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html